# Does Buck support headers with the same name as folders?

Tags: c++, buck

I am trying to build Eigen with [buck](/questions/tagged/buck). Unfortunately, Eigen has an unusual structure of headers:

```
Eigen/src/Cholesky/LLT.h
Eigen/src/Cholesky/LDLT.h
Eigen/src/Cholesky/...
Eigen/src/...
Eigen/Array
Eigen/Cholesky
Eigen/Core
Eigen/...
...
```

You can browse [the repo on GitHub](https://github.com/PX4/eigen).

I need to include `Eigen/Cholesky` and `Eigen/Cholesky/LLT.h` in the exported headers, but Buck considers this a conflict:

```py
prebuilt_cxx_library(
  name = 'eigen',
  header_only = True,
  header_namespace = 'Eigen', 
  exported_headers = subdir_glob([
    ('Eigen', '*'),
    ('Eigen/src', '**/*.h'),
  ]), 
  visibility = [
    'PUBLIC',
  ],
)
```

> java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: .../eigen/buck-out/gen/eigen#default,headers/Eigen/Cholesky

How can I have folders and files with the same name as exported headers in Buck?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the src folder should be part of the export, try this one:

```
prebuilt_cxx_library(
  name = 'eigen',
  header_only = True,
  header_namespace = 'Eigen', 
  exported_headers = subdir_glob([
    ('Eigen', '*'),
    ('Eigen', 'src/**/*.h'),
  ]), 
  visibility = [
    'PUBLIC',
  ],
)
```

Comment: To elaborate, this was an issue because there were two files with the same name in the different folders.  Having the `src` prefix avoids that.